# How to recover SA password for Sybase AWE?

Tags: passwords, password-recovery, sybase-ase15

I lost SA password for Sybase ASE, and Googled about this issue is about how to recover it. I have found some hints like edit the RUN_SERVER.bat and type -psa in the end of command line as:

> C:\sybase\ASE-15_0\bin\sqlsrvr.exe -dC:\sybase\data\master.dat -sMYSRV  -eC:\sybase\ASE-15_0\install\MYSRV.log -iC:\sybase\ini -MC:\sybase\ASE-15_0  -psa \

or in the first place(as somebody suggest for windows env)

> C:\sybase\ASE-15_0\bin\sqlsrvr.exe -psa -dC:\sybase\data\master.dat -sMYSRV  -eC:\sybase\ASE-15_0\install\MYSRV.log -iC:\sybase\ini -MC:\sybase\ASE-15_0

and I was waiting to see the following line: NEW SSO password for SA: somepassword,
then I can reset it using sp_password. But I the waited line did't appear in cmd screen.

Please, I do need help.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is correct, assuming your 'sa' login has sso_role. The positionof the -p flag is typically st the end but should make no difference. Note that the new password will only be on the screen/console, not in the ASE errorlog.

Post some screenshots if you want more help.

Comment: Thank you, So does sa has SSO_role  by default, cause I am not sure if it was? and if not is this the cause why I didn't see new password on the console.

Comment: Yes it does. The 'sa' login has both sa_role and sso_role by default. You can modify that however. But as long as you cannot log in as 'sa' that will be difficult to find out.

Comment: Dear, I gave up. after adding the -psa to the end of RUN_SID.bat file I right click on it then run as administrator and watch carefully the console screen but not found the sa new password. I tried this many many times , please any hint

Comment: Please post the full output from the console (copy it off the screen with your mouse) as well as the contents of your RUN_xxx.BAT file?